# React Router Redirect Conditional

Tags: reactjs, react-router, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a button that only redirects the user to a new page after validation is completed correctly.

Is there a way of doing something like this?
How to I get a Route to be activated inside of a class method?

```
import validator from './validator';

class Example {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.saveAndContinue = thos.saveAndContinue.bind(this)
  }

  saveAndContinue () {
    var valid = validator.validate(this.props.form)
    if (valid) {
      axios.post('/path')
      <Redirect to='/other_tab'>
    } else {
      validator.showErrors()
    }
  }

  render() {
    <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save and Continue</button>
  }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `this.props.history.push` instead of `<Redirect ... />`

Comment: @Purgatory Exactly right, thank you!

Comment: I have added an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed you should have access to the `history` object via `this.props.history` as described [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history).

If you look into the `push` function this will redirect you to any route you need. 
For example:

```
// Use push, replace, and go to navigate around.
this.props.history.push('/home', { some: 'state' })
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 1):

Like [Purgatory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079735/purgatory) said you can do it without using `<Redirect />`, but otherwise you could make your component a stateful component and then do a conditional render like so

```
render() {
    !this.state.redirect ? 
      <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save and Continue</button> :
      <Redirect to='/other_tab'>
  }
```

And let the `saveAndContinue()` change the component state.

```
saveAndContinue () {
    var valid = validator.validate(this.props.form)
    if (valid) {
      axios.post('/path')
      this.setState({redirect: true});
    } else {
      validator.showErrors()
    }
  }
```

When the state changes it would cause a re-render and this time the `<Redirect />` would be rendered.

**Note**: I didn't actually run this code snippet, so it may contain (hopefully minor) errors.

Comment: Minor typo fix:  

<Redirect to='/other_tab'  />

Redirect corresponding close tag.