# How do I conditionally redirect with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to redirect from a login screen to a home screen. How do I implement a conditional redirect correctly in ReactJS?

I have tried to redirect to components based on the state. this.state.loggedIn returns true or false as I expect it to do.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Router,
    Route,
    Link,
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
import history from '../history';
import LoginView from './LoginView';
import SearchPanel from './SearchPanel';
import "./style.css";


class App extends React.Component {
    state = { token: '', groupId: '', hostName: '', loggedIn: false};

    getLoginData = async (props) => {
        this.setState({loggedIn: true});
        console.log(this.state.loggedIn);
        this.setState({  token: props.token, groupId: props.token.groupId.data, hostName: props.token.hostName} );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div className="background">
                    <Route
                        exact
                        path="/"
                        render={() =>
                            !this.state.loggedIn ? (
                                history.replace("/login")
                            ) : (
                                history.replace("/home")
                            )
                        }
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/login"
                        component={() => <LoginView onLogin={this.getLoginData} />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/home"
                        component={() => (
                            <SearchPanel
                                token={this.state.token}
                                groupId={this.state.groupId}
                                hostName={this.state.hostName}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                </div>
            </Router>


        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I expect to be redirected to /home, but it stays on /login

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805930/react-router-redirect-conditional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Route/>` has an history object, use that
   `this.props.history.replace("/home")`

Using `.replace()` assures that the user can't navigate back to login again. Otherwise use `.push()`.

Comment: I passed a history prop to my router and used .push and/or .replace for both cases. still the same result

Comment: Check this it works, it's your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/olnyzr826q . change `loggedIn` state manually and go to `"/"` from address bar and refresh.

Comment: That does work indeed, but it doesn't automatically redirect the user when the state is changed.

Comment: And where are you changing the State? Every `setState` re renders hence will work.

Comment: I edited the code in my original question. This time with the history prop. I edit the state in getLoginData()

Comment: Import history from ".\history"? Why have you declared your own history? I'll look the code on laptop.

Comment: I fixed it! I had to redirect it to "/" after I changed the state. Otherwise it would always  skip the render() in the first Route and stay on "/login"

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging my effort. Yes, that's what I did manually in example. Good luck. Keep posting at Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this today.
Here's my code, mind i decided to make this a HOC that you can choose to wrap or not wrap.
For use cases that have multiple redirect cases you'll definitely want to use this inline instead of as a wrapper.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Redirect} from 'react-router';

interface IConditionalRedirectProps {
    shouldRedirect: boolean,
    to: string
}

export const ConditionalRedirect: React.FC<IConditionalRedirectProps> = (props) => {
    const {shouldRedirect, to, children} = props;

    if (shouldRedirect) {
        console.log('redirecting');
        return <Redirect to={to}/>
    } else {
        return (
            <>
                {children}
            </>
        )
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
<ConditionalRedirect shouldRedirect={someFunctionThatReturnsBool()}
                             to={'some url'}>
    <Normal Elements here>
</ConditionalRedirect>
```