# change switch main path according to api

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, routes, react-router

React(hooks)beginner here, at the moment when driver or admin goes to website it is like this(example):
App.js:

```html
  <div className="app">
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/a">
          <A />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/c">
          <C />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/b">
          <B />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Redirect to="/a" />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
```

As you can see main path is this :   `<Route path="/"> <Redirect to="/a" /> </Route>`

Here is what i'm getting from an API:

{
"id": "2222",
"name": "Random2",
"isAdmin": true,
"isDriver": false,
"isCustomer": false,
"company": {
"id": "11111",
"name": "Random"

}
}

my point is how change main path, for example if   "isCustomer": true, then main path is `< Route path="/"> <Redirect to="/g" /> </Route>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Redirect Conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805930/react-router-redirect-conditional)

Comment: since everybody said Hooks are easier to start with i started with it, i have no idea how classes works

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested but my hunch is something along the lines of:

Use `useState` to hold the default route and update the default route if the result of your api call says it's a customer. Pass the state to the `Redirect`.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect } from "react";

...

const [ defaultRoute, setDefaultRoute ] = useState("/a");

...

useEffect( () => {}, [
  ...fetch api stuff...
  
  if(isCustomer()) setDefaultRoute("/g");
]);

...

return (<div className="app">
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/a">
          <A />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/c">
          <C />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/b">
          <B />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Redirect to={defaultRoute} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>);
```

Comment: for testing purpose could you use { "id": "2222", "name": "Random2", "isAdmin": true, "isDriver": false, "isCustomer": false, "company": { "id": "11111", "name": "Random"

} } and have some working demo ? if possible ?